# Using UiTextField as a phone number input to text

Tags: xcode, uitextview

I'm making an app that I need to input a phone number to text . 
Is their a way to do that with uitextfield or some other way where the person can type the phone number of the receiver ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use text field and define keyboard type:

```
 [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

Comment: Would that get the app to use the text as a phone number reference ? I basically need the person to type in a phone number and the app uses the phone number to send a text

Answer (score 0):

You can set the keyboard type from the interface builder

here is example for how to select keyboard type to UITextField

http://screencast.com/t/uJxOBialte

Comment: Guys your not getting what I'm trying to do . My app is basically an sms sender with text field . In the text field you put a phone number and when you hit send it sends the text to receivers phone which was the phone number

Comment: Ok so all you need is UITextField with PhoneNumber keyboard

Comment: And that's it like can you show a source code of what to do I'm new sorry